# Sitecore make items moveable in experience editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8.1

Hei I have the following task:

I have a folder with few items in content editor (contacts)

I want to make a view where I show all the items in the folder, but I would like those who use the experience editor to edit data for each item in the list and also change the order of those.

Can anybody explain what steps should I take in order to achieve something like this in Sitecore 8 ?

I am using a MVC project for this and Sitecore 8.1

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The sort can be done by using an EditFrame with an up and down button.

Iterate through the items in the folder and give each item an editFrame in the HTML and bind the item to the editFrame. Making fields editable use the default methods or your framework. `@Html.Sitecore().Field("My Field Name", theItem)`

The editFrame on eache item looks like this:

[image: Sort items in Experience editor]

Use item:moveup and item:movedown simulair to the default Up and Down Custom Experience Buttons.

See [User friendly developing with the Sitecore Experience Editor](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/the-experience-editor/) Example for Insert and Sort with Custom Experience Buttons and Edit frame